# Does the prompt manager escape characters?

Tags: escaping, sas, prompt

I am working on a SAS program and I created a prompt which should allow a user to enter a comma separated list of values. The values are then used in a `WHERE IN` clause. The problem is that the prompt manager appears to be escaping the quotes, somehow, resulting in weird error messages.

To show the error, I've created this sample data set:

```
DATA Work.Birds;

    LENGTH  Category    $   20
            CommonName  $   27
            ;

    INPUT   Category    $   1-20
            CommonName  $   22-48
            ;

DATALINES;
Ostriches            Common Ostrich
Ostriches            Greater Rhea
Cassowaries and Emus Southern Cassowary
Cassowaries and Emus Dwarf Cassowary
Kiwis                Brown Kiwi
Kiwis                Little Spotted Kiwi
Waterfowls           Horned Screamer
Waterfowls           Magpie-goose
Penguins             Emperor Penguin
Penguins             King Penguin
RUN;
```

Now, using a `%LET` statement, I can write a more-or-less-dynamic query for particular birds:

```
%LET BirdCategories = 'Kiwis', 'Penguins';

%PUT "&BirdCategories.";

PROC SQL NOPRINT;
    CREATE TABLE Work.SelectedBirds AS
    SELECT      *
    FROM        Work.Birds
    WHERE       Category IN ( &BirdCategories. )
    ;
QUIT;
```

This code prints the following to the log:

```
"'Kiwis', 'Penguins'"
```

It also creates a dataset with four records.

Now I try to create a prompt using the prompt manager with the instructions found in the [official documentation](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/041-2010.pdf). The goal is to replace the single `%LET` line with a prompt *without adding any additional code*.

So I created a prompt named BirdCategories and set the Number of Values to "Single Value":

[image: Screen-shot of first tab]

[image: Screen-shot of second tab]

I then run the program again (this time commenting out the `%LET` statement):

[image: Sceen-shot of prompt]

The log outputs the following for BirdCategories:

```
"'Kiwis', 'Waterfowls'"
```

But I get an error in my SQL statement:

```
43             PROC SQL NOPRINT;
44                 CREATE TABLE Work.SelectedBirds AS
45                 SELECT      *
46                 FROM        Work.Birds
47                 WHERE       Category IN ( &BirdCategories. )

           _
           22
           200
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
              a missing value, (, -, SELECT.  

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

48                 ;
NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and will continue to check the syntax of statements.
49             QUIT;
```

(I get the same error whether I use `PROC SQL` or a `DATA` step with a `WHERE IN` clause.)

Then I tried inputting `Kiwis", "Waterfowls` with the following code:

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
    CREATE TABLE Work.SelectedBirds AS
    SELECT      "&BirdCategories."
    FROM        Work.Birds
    ;
QUIT;
```

which should create two columns, but instead I get this:

[image: One column with embedded quotes rather than two columns]

If I set the macro variable with a SYMPUT, like so:

```
DATA _NULL_;    
    CALL SYMPUT( 'BirdCategories', 'Kiwis", "Penguins' );
RUN;
```

I get two columns as expected:

[image: two columns]

I can't see it, but the prompt manager must be escaping my quote characters somehow. Any clue what's going on? I've tried my google-fu to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
    CREATE TABLE Work.SelectedBirds AS
    SELECT      *
    FROM        Work.Birds
    WHERE       Category IN ( %unquote(&BirdCategories.) )
    ;
QUIT;
```

I think it works as expected from my testing.  %UNQUOTE is one of the many handy tricks for dealing with this stuff.

Comment: It worked! Does the prompt manager add quotes? Why do they not appear in the `%PUT` statement? (I am relatively new to SAS... please forgive my ignorance)

Comment: It doesn't add quotes per se; what it (apparently) adds are nonprintable characters that escape the value.  Probably something similar to what %str( ) or %nrstr( ) do.  Don't worry about ignorance, in this field I'm not far ahead of you; every time SAS-L includes a posting about macro quoting I get lost almost immediately.

Comment: You rock. That was driving me and a colleague crazy for like 2 hours. Do you know of any documentation for this "feature"?

Comment: I don't know anything about Prompt Manager (I mostly use non-EG SAS).  It's probably a safety feature (so that funky characters in the prompt manager don't cause unexpected results).  %NRSTR/etc. are heavily covered if you google 'macro quoting'; there's a raft of documentation/papers/confused people.

Comment: From what I've read, Prompt Manager prompts are essentially a variant of the Stored Process prompts.  Thus, this might suffice for documentation for your purposes: [SAS Documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/stpug/61271/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003152642.htm).  It also suggests a slightly safer/better way than %UNQUOTE if you are solely interested in quotation marks (the [STPSRV_UNQUOTE2](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/stpug/61271/HTML/default/viewer.htm#srvuquot.htm) Function).

Comment: I'd also recommend reaching out to [Chris Hemedinger](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/author/chrishemedinger/) who is a SAS employee, and one of their more knowledgeable folks about various EG elements.  One of the SAS-produced papers I read about Prompt Manager ([this one](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/309-2011.pdf) mentions him as a resource, though it didn't include anything useful for you I don't think.